# sql code system table code meaning

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

What does below code trying to do?

```
select * from tempdb.dbo.sysobjects
where id = object_id(N'tempdb..#val_load_data')
```

Thanks
Bruce

Comment: Trying to retrieve the metadata relating to that temporary table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an existance check; if that table exists, then there will be a row returned.

Comment: An existence check would just need to call the object_id function and check if it is null. No need to use the result in a select.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be checking `tempdb` for the existence and details of a temp table called `#val_load_data`.

If a row is returned the table exists.